# (swipeLeft) doesn't work with hammerjs - what's wrong?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swipe, hammer.js

i want my Mobile-App (using Ionic) to navigate to the next page when being swiped, but neither the device recognises my touch, nor does the web page on localhost.

Since the terminal doesn't show me any errors I'm kind of confused.

How can I fix this?

**app.module.ts:**

```js
import 'hammerjs';
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';
import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG} from '@angular/platform-browser';

export class HammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  overrides = {
    swipe: { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL },
  } as any;
}
```

**tab1.page.ts:**

```js
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Tab2Page } from '../tab2/tab2.page';
import { Tab3Page } from '../tab3/tab3.page';

swipeLeftEvent(e) {
   if (e.direction == 2) {
       //direction 2 = left page
       this.navCtrl.navigateForward('tab3.page.html')
   }
}

swipeRightEvent(e) {
   if (e.direction == 4) {
       //direction 4 = right page.
       this.navCtrl.navigateForward('tab2.page.html')
   }
}
```

**tab1.page.html:**

```html
<ion-content (swipeLeft)="swipeLeftEvent($event)" (swipeRight)="swipeRightEvent($event)">
  <div *ngIf="!type">
  </div>

  <ion-list *ngIf="type && !sub_type">
  </ion-list>

  <ion-list *ngIf="sub_type">
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

The code is similar on the other pages.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import { HammerGestureConfig, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HammerModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import * as Hammer from 'hammerjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
    buildHammer(element: HTMLElement): any {
      return new Hammer(element, {
        swipe: { direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL }
      });
   }
}

imports: [
    HammerModule
],
providers: [
    {
      provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
      useClass: MyHammerConfig,
    },
]
```